# Добавление в ListView через SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: java, android, cursoradaper

Делаю программу словаря с русского на английский и наоборот.

Есть форма со `Spinner`, где выбирается направление перевода. Есть текстовое поле `txtSearch` для поиска слов и есть `ListView`, куда выводятся слова из таблиц БД в зависимости от направления перевода. Слова из таблиц в `ListView` вывожу через свой адаптер на основе `SimpleCursorAdapter`.

Это код адаптера:

```
public class MyCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {
    private int layout;
    DBHeler db;
    Context ctx;

    MyCursorAdapter(Context ctx, int layout, Cursor cursor, String[] from, int[] to, DBHeler db) {
        super(ctx, layout, cursor, from, to);
        this.layout = layout;
        this.db = db;
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(layout, parent, false);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

        String bukva = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Contract.Entry.COLUMN_SLOVO)).substring(0, 1).toUpperCase();
        final String slovo = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Contract.Entry.COLUMN_SLOVO));
        final String izbrannoe = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Contract.Entry.COLUMN_IZBRANNOE));

        TextView txtBukva = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtBukva);
        TextView txtSlovo = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtSlovo);
        final ImageButton btnIzbrannoe = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btnIzbrannoe);

        txtBukva.setText(bukva);
        txtSlovo.setText(slovo);
        btnIzbrannoe.setFocusable(false);

        if (izbrannoe.equals("1")) {
            btnIzbrannoe.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_star_yellow);
        } else if (izbrannoe.equals("0")) {
            btnIzbrannoe.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_star_outline_black);
        }

        btnIzbrannoe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (izbrannoe.equals("1")) {
                    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                    values.put(Contract.Entry.COLUMN_IZBRANNOE, "0");
                    long newRowId = db.database.update(Contract.Entry.TABLE_RUEN, values, Contract.Entry.COLUMN_SLOVO + "= ?", new String[]{slovo});
                    if (newRowId == -1) {
                        Toast.makeText(ctx, "Ошибка", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(ctx, "Удалено из избранное", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        btnIzbrannoe.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_star_outline_black);
                    }
                } else if (izbrannoe.equals("0")) {
                    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                    values.put(Contract.Entry.COLUMN_IZBRANNOE, "1");
                    long newRowId = db.database.update(Contract.Entry.TABLE_RUEN, values, Contract.Entry.COLUMN_SLOVO + "= ?", new String[]{slovo});
                    if (newRowId == -1) {
                        Toast.makeText(ctx, "Ошибка", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(ctx, "Добавлено в избранное", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        btnIzbrannoe.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_star_yellow);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Это основной код MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AutoCompleteTextView txtSearch;
    private Spinner spinner;
    private ListView list;
    private ImageButton btnClear;

    DBHeler db;

    private MyCursorAdapter myCursorAdapter;
    private Cursor cursor;
    String[] from;
    int[] to;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        db = new DBHeler(this);

        try {
            db.createDataBase();
            db.openDataBase();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        // Настраиваем адаптер
        ArrayAdapter<?> adapter =
                ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.types, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        // Вызываем адаптер
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        txtSearch = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.txtSearch);
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        btnClear = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnClear);

        /*Выводим в список все слова, при запуске программы*/
        String selectedItem = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

        if (selectedItem.equals("С русского на английский")) {
            cursor = db.getRuWords();
            from = new String[] {Contract.Entry.COLUMN_SLOVO, Contract.Entry.COLUMN_SLOVO, Contract.Entry.COLUMN_IZBRANNOE};
            to = new int[] {R.id.txtBukva, R.id.txtSlovo, R.id.btnIzbrannoe};
            myCursorAdapter = new MyCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.item, cursor, from, to, db);
            list.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);
        } else if (selectedItem.equals("С английского на русский")) {
            cursor = db.getEnWords();
            from = new String[] {Contract.Entry.COLUMN_SLOVO, Contract.Entry.COLUMN_SLOVO, Contract.Entry.COLUMN_IZBRANNOE};
            to = new int[] {R.id.txtBukva, R.id.txtSlovo, R.id.btnIzbrannoe};
            myCursorAdapter = new MyCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.item, cursor, from, to, db);
            list.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        txtSearch.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
                if (b && txtSearch.getText().toString().length() > 0)
                    btnClear.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                else
                    btnClear.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        });

        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SlovoActivity.class);
                CharSequence strCharSequence = ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtSlovo)).getText();
                String str = strCharSequence.toString().toLowerCase().trim();
                String selectedItem = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                if (selectedItem.equals("С русского на английский")) {
                    intent.putExtra("slovo", str);
                    intent.putExtra("type", "RU");
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else if (selectedItem.equals("С английского на русский")) {
                    intent.putExtra("slovo", str);
                    intent.putExtra("type", "EN");
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });

        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                txtSearch.setText("");
                String str = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
                if (str.equals("С русского на английский")) {
                    cursor = db.getRuWords();
                    myCursorAdapter = new MyCursorAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.item, cursor, from, to, db);
                    list.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);
                } else if (str.equals("С английского на русский")) {
                    cursor = db.getEnWords();
                    myCursorAdapter = new MyCursorAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.item, cursor, from, to, db);
                    list.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Вот код классов для подключения к БД, запроса данных в курсоры и т.д.:

```
public class Contract {
    private Contract() {
    };

    public static final class Entry implements BaseColumns {
        public final static String TABLE_RUEN = "ruen";
        public final static String TABLE_ENRU = "enru";

        public final static String _ID = BaseColumns._ID;
        public final static String COLUMN_SLOVO = "slovo";
        public final static String COLUMN_PEREVOD = "perevod";
        public final static String COLUMN_IZBRANNOE = "izbrannoe";
    }
}
```

Класс DBHelper:

```
public class DBHeler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    //Пусть к БД
    private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/tests.mytest/databases/";
    //Имя файла базы данных
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "dbase.db";
    //Версия базы данных. При изменении схемы увеличить на единицу
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    //Объектная переменная типа SQLiteDatabase
    public SQLiteDatabase database;
    private Context myContext;

    final String ruQuery = "SELECT * " + " FROM " + Contract.Entry.TABLE_RUEN;
    //запрос, позволяет вывести все слова из колонки word
    final String enQuery = "SELECT * " + " FROM " + Contract.Entry.TABLE_ENRU;

    //Конструктор
    //Третий параметр null в суперклассе используется для работы с курсорами. Сейчас их не используем, поэтому оставим в покое.
    public DBHeler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.myContext = context;
    }

    public Cursor getRuWords() {
        return database.rawQuery(ruQuery, null); //в курсор выбираем все слова из запроса
    }

    public Cursor getEnWords() {
        return database.rawQuery(enQuery, null); //в курсор выбираем все слова из запроса
    }

    public void createDataBase() throws IOException {
        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

        if(dbExist){
            //ничего не делать - база уже есть
        }else{
            //вызывая этот метод создаем пустую базу, позже она будет перезаписана
            this.getReadableDatabase();

            try {
                copyDataBase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new Error("Error copying database");
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean checkDataBase(){
        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
        try {
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        } catch(SQLiteException e){
            //база еще не существует
        }
        if(checkDB != null){
            checkDB.close();
        }
        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }

    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{
        //Открываем локальную БД как входящий поток
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);

        //Путь ко вновь созданной БД
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;

        //Открываем пустую базу данных как исходящий поток
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        //перемещаем байты из входящего файла в исходящий
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        //закрываем потоки
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();
    }

    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {
        //открываем БД
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
        //database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {
        if(database != null)
            database.close();
        super.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
}
```

Проблема:

С методом `btnIzbrannoe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()` добавление в избранное получилось, но когда второй раз нажимаю на `btnIzbrannoe`, чтобы удалить из избранного не работает. Т.е. не удаляет из избранного. Иконка кнопки меняется, а на самом деле не удаляет из избранного.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51361/discussion-on-question-by------simplecursoradap).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема связана с тем, что вы вносите изменения в БД, а значение курсора, по которому вы ориентируетесь при обработке клика остается со старыми данными. В качестве решения можно использовать массив - локальную переменную, которая будет хранить актуальное состояние избранных в текущей сессии:

```
public class MyCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {
    private int layout;
    DBHeler db;
    Context ctx;
    boolean[] favorite;

    MyCursorAdapter(Context ctx, int layout, Cursor cursor, String[] from, int[] to, DBHeler db) {
        super(ctx, layout, cursor, from, to);
        this.layout = layout;
        this.db = db;
        this.ctx = ctx;
        favorite = new boolean[cursor.getCount()];
        // заполняем первоначальные состояния избранного из БД
        int i = 0;
        while (cursor.moveToNext() ) {
          String fav = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Contract.Entry.COLUMN_IZBRANNOE));
          favorite[i] = (fav.equals("1")) ? true: false;
          i = i++;
        }
     // восстанавливаем позицию курсора после итерации
     cursor.moveToPosition(-1); 
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(layout, parent, false);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

        String bukva = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Contract.Entry.COLUMN_SLOVO)).substring(0, 1).toUpperCase();
        final String slovo = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Contract.Entry.COLUMN_SLOVO));
        // текущая позиция в курсоре
        final int pos = cursor.getPosition();

        TextView txtBukva = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtBukva);
        TextView txtSlovo = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtSlovo);
        final ImageButton btnIzbrannoe = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btnIzbrannoe);

        txtBukva.setText(bukva);
        txtSlovo.setText(slovo);
        btnIzbrannoe.setFocusable(false);

        if (favorite[pos]) {
            btnIzbrannoe.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_star_yellow);
        } else  {
            btnIzbrannoe.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_star_outline_black);
        }

        btnIzbrannoe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (favorite[pos]) {
                    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                    values.put(Contract.Entry.COLUMN_IZBRANNOE, "0");
                    long newRowId = db.database.update(Contract.Entry.TABLE_RUEN, values, Contract.Entry.COLUMN_SLOVO + "= ?", new String[]{slovo});
                    if (newRowId == -1) {
                        Toast.makeText(ctx, "Ошибка", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(ctx, "Удалено из избранное", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        btnIzbrannoe.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_star_outline_black);

                    }
                } else {
                    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                    values.put(Contract.Entry.COLUMN_IZBRANNOE, "1");
                    long newRowId = db.database.update(Contract.Entry.TABLE_RUEN, values, Contract.Entry.COLUMN_SLOVO + "= ?", new String[]{slovo});
                    if (newRowId == -1) {
                        Toast.makeText(ctx, "Ошибка", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(ctx, "Добавлено в избранное", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        btnIzbrannoe.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_star_yellow);
                    }
                }
                // инвертируем значение в вспомогательном массиве
                favorite[pos] = !favorite[pos];
            }
        });
    }
}
```

писал "на коленке", возможны мелкие недочеты, но общий алгоритм, думаю понятен

НО! я бы сделал все совершенно иначе, но это большой объем работы. Во первых использовал класс `CursorLoader` для подгрузки данных из БД в список, он решает несколько серьезных проблем, как актуальность курсора, своевременное закрытие и сохранение при изменении состояния, асинхронная работа не тормозящая UI. Всю логику управления избранным вынес из адаптера в активити (обработку клика по кнопке избранного), это позволит отвязаться от фиксированного курсора.

Comment: Спасибо. Попробую сначала тогда почитать о cursoradapter

Comment: @Вероника CursorLoader видимо, а не CursorAdapter

Comment: да, перепутала)

Comment: пытаюсь как тут http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/278-urok-136-cursorloader.html сделать все через  CursorLoader . Но программа сразу вылетает. Вот что выдает в логи

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: ModernAsyncTask #1
Process: tests.mytest2, PID: 4155
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
at android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask$3.done(ModernAsyncTask.java:161) и т.д.

Comment: @Вероника Создайте новый вопрос с этой проблемой

Answer (score 0):

Это меняете в MainActivity

```
from = new String[] {Contract.Entry._ID, Contract.Entry.COLUMN_SLOVO, Contract.Entry.COLUMN_SLOVO, Contract.Entry.COLUMN_IZBRANNOE};
```

Также в начале bindView в адаптере около

```
String bukva = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Contract.Entry.COLUMN_SLOVO)).substring(0, 1).toUpperCase();
    final String slovo = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Contract.Entry.COLUMN_SLOVO));
    final String izbrannoe = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Contract.Entry.COLUMN_IZBRANNOE));
```

добавляете

```
int _ID = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Contract.Entry._ID));
```

потом после инициализации `btnIzbrannoe` добавляете:

```
btnIzbrannoe.setTag(_ID);
```

и Listener:

```
btnIzbrannoe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String id = String.valueOf(view.getTag());
                Cursor getFav = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + Contract.Entry.TABLE_RUEN + " WHERE " + Contract.Entry._ID + " = " + id, null);
                if(getFav != null && getFav.moveToFirst()){
                    String izbrannoe = getFav.getString(getFav.getColumnIndex(Contract.Entry.COLUMN_IZBRANNOE));
                    if (izbrannoe.equals("1")) {
                        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                        values.put(Contract.Entry.COLUMN_IZBRANNOE, "0");
                        long newRowId = db.database.update(Contract.Entry.TABLE_RUEN, values, Contract.Entry.COLUMN_SLOVO + "= ?", new String[]{slovo});
                        if (newRowId == -1) {
                            Toast.makeText(ctx, "Ошибка", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(ctx, "Удалено из избранное", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            btnIzbrannoe.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_star_outline_black);
                        }
                    } else if (izbrannoe.equals("0")) {
                        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                        values.put(Contract.Entry.COLUMN_IZBRANNOE, "1");
                        long newRowId = db.database.update(Contract.Entry.TABLE_ENRU, values, Contract.Entry.COLUMN_SLOVO + "= ?", new String[]{slovo});
                        if (newRowId == -1) {
                            Toast.makeText(ctx, "Ошибка", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(ctx, "Добавлено в избранное", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            btnIzbrannoe.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_star_yellow);
                        }
                    }
                    if(!getFav.isClosed()){
                        getFav.close();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: попробовала. Добавить получается, затем когда хочу удалить  опять пишет добавлено в избранное.

Comment: @Вероника обновил ответ, попробуйте

Comment: можно пример? как это решается? если вторую проверку убрать то как потом добавлять слова в избранные?

Comment: поэтому я и говорю что простой вариант хранить избранные в SharedPreferences чтобы не обращаться к базе данных, легче же обратиться к SP

Comment: давайте я спрошу так :) есть моя структура БД, есть listView с двумя TextView и Imagebutton. Данные выводятся. Как бы Вы реализовали добавление/удаление из избранного? Без SharedPreferences и других штучек :)

Comment: @Вероника я же написал в ответе как, каждый раз обращаться к БД, как кликаешь по избранному, иначе только через SP

Comment: @Вероника Разделение связанных данных (как слова и их наличие в избранном) по разным хранилищам, тем более имеющим разные системы запросов и идентификации (ID в БД и ключ в преференсах) очень плохая затея. Если при статической БД это еще может внешне выглядеть приемлемым и будет работать, хотя уже при сотнях в избранном преференсы будут слабым звеном по производительности, то при внесении изменеий в БД (добавление, удаление слов) начнется хаос, синхронизировать эти хранилища будет трудной задачей.

Comment: Я не хочу использовать другие хранилища. Есть БД с ней ведется вся работа

Comment: данный метод у меня не сработал. Т.е. иконка меняется, но в БД не обновляется